# rsync: how to ignore remote file that is locked - Device or resource busy (16)

Tags: rsync

I'm using rsync to copy files, and use --delete. rsync is trying to delete an .nfs file, and fails as follows:

```
rsync: delete_file: unlink(/path/.nfs0000083729d3947392020000099) failed: Device or resource busy (16)
```

This is expected because rsync should not attempt to delete nfs files. But how to tell rsync to ignore this file?

My rsync command is

```
sync -avzq -e 'ssh -i /ssh/key' origin_dir myuser@myhost:/destination_dir --delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to command line:

```
 --filter '-_.nfs*'
```

Actually, I included -C in order to also ignore some files that are unuseful at destination:

```
-C --filter '-_.nfs*
```

The options above are described in... the place I should have started... the man page!   https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I ended up removing with -C, because it didn't allow rsync to run . -C can be useful, but depends on each case.